# Common Microsoft Office 2010 crash

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-office-2010, addons

Just recently I have installed office professional 2010 on my laptop. Whenever I open up any program from Office such as Word, Excel, Power Point, etc. The program will shut down and I cannot load or alter any files. So I did some search on some forums and found the following to be the most common fix to the issue on [this](http://www.articlesbase.com/software-articles/word-2010-crashes-how-to-fix-microsoft-word-2010-crash-3613792.html) site. I am most interested in removing/uninstalling officetab 1.22 add-on.

Can someone please step me through on how to uninstall this add-on. Im not familiary with removing add-ons for Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a very complete answer, but then again, you have a zero percent answer acceptance rate.

Look at this [Microsoft Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-or-remove-add-ins-HP010342658.aspx) and this also might help (its for 2007).

It should have everything you need.